# How many times and on what method should the ads be loaded?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

So I am trying to understand how many times an add must be loaded if it will shown when the user clicks on a button. On the official implementation guide, it is done once on the onCreate method. So could I put it onStart method? Or maybe onResume method? So my question is, in my example, how many times and on what method should I call CallNewInertial()? This is my code:

```
  private void CallNewInertial() {
        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(MainActivity.this);
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.adMob_interstitial),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                    }
                });
    }


private void OnClick(){
       if (mInterstitialAd != null ) {

                    mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);

                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                           // SUPPOSE that startactivity moves to another activity;
                            startActivity(i);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {

                        }



                    });

                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling it in `onCreate()` would be the best programming practice to load the ad on the creation of the activity then you can show the ad complying with the Interstitial ad [flow and guidance](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980). As said in guidance:

> Don't surprise users with interstitial ads. Placing interstitial ads
> so that they suddenly appear when a user is focused on a task at hand may lead to accidental clicks and often creates a frustrating user experience

If you think that whenever user comes back to this activity from another activity and interstitial should be shown then you can call `CallNewInertial()` in `onStart()` method because `onCreate()` won't be called here and your ad won't be loaded.

Depends on the use case although I don't recommend overwhelming the user with interstitial ads on the same activity again and again because as said in guidance:

> Don't overwhelm users with interstitial ads. Repeated interstitial ads
> often lead to poor user experiences and accidental clicks.

So I would say just go through with the flow and guidance of the interstitial ads then you can make this decision.

Comment: Hi @UndefinedBug1.0 , so as you have recommended me, I have put the CallNewInertial onStart() method. So the ad is shown when the user clicks a button and later I have put onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() to move to other activity. Later the user can move again to the first activity. It works fine, but the problem is that I don´t know why the ad is not shown in the first click, it starts to show after the second click. I have noticed that on the first click the intertitial is equal to null, so in the first click is not loaded...

Comment: I have added my code that shows the intertiitial.

Comment: You need to give it a moment to load the interstitial when you come back to the activity so maybe when you clicked the button first time, it wasn't loaded yet and on your second click, it got loaded. Use `Log.d` to check whether the interstitial is loaded yet or not.

Comment: Yeah, @UndefinedBug1.0, so when I click the button for the first time it is not loaded yet. How can I make to make the ad be loaded before the first click so that in the first click the ad is shown as it is loaded?

Comment: Disable the button initially either in XML or in `onStart()` method where you are loading the ad. Then in `onAdLoaded()` method, you can enable it again. Like `button.setEnabled(true)'

Comment: edit: I have noticed that if I wait like 7 second it works on the first click, I don´t understand why